# pass img to controller in Razor

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on an ASP.net MVC4 application and I want to send an Image that I have on my view to the controller through a form
Here is my View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                            { 

                            <img src="img/annonceBrute.JPG" width ="60" height="60" name ="imageFile"  />

                            @Html.TextArea("resultText")
                            <input type="submit" style="margin-left:40px;cursor:pointer;" id="l" value="Envoyer"/>
                          }
```

And in my controller I have a code that works with uploaded image but I want to use an image that already exists in my view. Here is the code of the controller

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
    {
        var db = new Bd_scanitEntities();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.JournalSet
          .Select(c => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value = c.Id.ToString(),
              Text = c.label
          });
        ViewBag.IdJournal1 = items;

      //Conversion
        if (imageFile!= null && imageFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            // for now just fail hard if there's any error however in a propper app I would expect a full demo.

            using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(Server.MapPath(@"./tessdata"), "eng", EngineMode.Default))
            {
                // have to load Pix via a bitmap since Pix doesn't support loading a stream.
                using (var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imageFile.InputStream))
                {
                    using (var pix = PixConverter.ToPix(image))
                    {
                        using (var page = engine.Process(pix))
                        {
                            //meanConfidenceLabel.InnerText = String.Format("{0:P}", page.GetMeanConfidence());
                            //ViewBag.meanConfidenceLabel = String.Format("{0:P}", page.GetMeanConfidence());
                            ViewBag.resultText = page.GetText();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return View();
    }
```

My problem is that I don't know which type I should use in the index argument in order to get the image from the view .

Comment: I think you need a simple GET request handler. `HttpPostedFileBase` should be used with a POST request handler.

Comment: The images there is on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send image to controller this way, if you only need the path of the image on controller, use hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="image" value="img/annonceBrute.JPG"/>
```

if you want the whole image to be posted on server, you need to use `input type file` you can't post a html display tag to server using form, in form only **input fields** are posted on server.

in controller action you can read file like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection form)
{

    string filePath = Server.MapPath(form["image"].ToString());    

    byte[] buffer;   //file bytes
      FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      try
      {
        int length = (int)fileStream.Length;  // get file length
        buffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer
        int count;                            // actual number of bytes read
        int sum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read

        // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
        while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
          sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
      }
      finally
      {
        fileStream.Close();
      }
      return View();
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Then on your Controller, you can get a `Path` of a Image by `Server.MatpPath("~/img/annonceBrute.JPG")`

Answer (score 1):

As it looks that you wants to upload image from view and Get HttpPostedFileBase in controller so use input file tag

```
<input id="image1" name="image1" type="file"  />
```

in Controller action you should get HttpPosted file like this

```
 if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (Request.Files["image1"].ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFileBase pf = Request.Files["image1"]
                    }                       
                }
```

Now you can save this `HttpPostedFileBase` or what ever is your requirement